# Getting solid shape of dam lake in 3D by using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis-3

I am working on a plugin. I will get a raster map of a dam lake for instance. When load that map I want to get a 3D model which fills the lake entirely. Then I will divide the lake on horizontal view and cross section (by giving segment number).

At the end of the day, I should get every box of this segmentation. I try to illustrate that above:

[image]

Is it possible that make in QGIS 3.x by using 3D attribute?

Comment: that is one odd cross section for a lake...anyways, if I get this right, and a 3D volume model is what you are after, you'd need quite a sophisticated set of data to make that happen, e.g. lake floor DEM etc., and creating a volumetric grid will be challenging. I guess there's specialized (and possibly proprietary) 3D hydrologic modeling software out there that's better suited than QGIS.

Comment: Do you have the lake bathymetry (lake floor terrain, like @ThingumaBob asked)? And I didn't understand, the way the lines crosses the lake in plan view, it give the impression you want transversal sections, but the picture below shows a longitudinal section...